# Ruby on Rails tutorial test 10..20

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does anybody could  pass test 10.20 Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Harty?
I have errors as below that I could not comprehend; besides I followed instruction on tutorial exactly.

For ex. Tutorial said to change to noreply@example.com"]
        But it point to error to this line……
Should I change this line and inform Michael Harty about bug/do something else to fix error?

I use: ruby-2.3.0 rails - 4.2.2

**errors:**

> ERROR["test_account_activation", UserMailerTest, 2016-03-23 16:43:45
>   +0000]  test_account_activation#UserMailerTest (1458751425.73s) ArgumentError:         ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given
>   0, expected 1)
>               app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:3:in `account_activation'
>               test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:6:in`block in '
>           app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:3:in `account_activation'
>           test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:6:in`block in '
>
> FAIL["test_password_reset", UserMailerTest, 2016-03-23 16:43:45
>   +0000]  test_password_reset#UserMailerTest (1458751425.83s)
>           Expected: ["from@example.com"]
>             Actual: ["noreply@example.com"]
>           test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:16:in `block in '
>
> 39/39:
>   [=============================================================] 100%
>   Time: 00:00:03, Time: 00:00:03

```
// user_mailer.rb

    class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

      def account_activation(user)
        @user = user
        mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
      end

      def password_reset
        @greeting = "Hi"

        mail to: "to@example.org"
      end
    end




//user_mailer_test.rb


require 'test_helper'


class UserMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase


  test "account_activation" do


    mail = UserMailer.account_activation


    assert_equal "Account activation", mail.subject


    assert_equal ["to@example.org"], mail.to


    assert_equal ["from@example.com"], mail.from


    assert_match "Hi", mail.body.encoded

  end

  test "password_reset" do

    mail = UserMailer.password_reset

    assert_equal "Password reset", mail.subject

    assert_equal ["to@example.org"], mail.to

    assert_equal ["from@example.com"], mail.from

    assert_match "Hi", mail.body.encoded

  end


end
```

I add the file changing Michael to Tatyana but still got 1 error as below:I find this file and add it changing michael to tatyana but still got error as below:
ERROR["test_account_activation", UserMailerTest, 2016-03-23 16:43:44 +0000]
 test_account_activation#UserMailerTest (1458751424.20s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
            app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_user_mailer_account_activation_html_erb__2380038393264600902_67365800'
            app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:5:in`account_activation'
            test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:UserMailerTest>'
        app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb:9:in`_app_views_user_mailer_account_activation_html_erb__2380038393264600902_67365800'
        app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:5:in `account_activation'
        test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:9:in`block in '

Comment: to 7urkm3n: I had this file but i still has one error pointing that I have Template Error that host is missing??  I don't think that I supposed to change template but to get rid from error, I've added local host 3000, and it is still pointing to syntax error in host.... How to fix it and pass test 10.20  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**UserMailer.account_activation** method needs **user** parameter in test.

```
class UserMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase

  test "account_activation" do
    mail = UserMailer.account_activation(User.create(email: "foo@bar.com"))
    assert_equal "Account activation", mail.subject
    assert_equal ["to@example.org"], mail.to
    assert_equal ["from@example.com"], mail.from
    assert_match "Hi", mail.body.encoded
  end
end
```

Comment: please provide more  details  with example if you know how to achieve it. thanks.

Comment: I have exactly the same file and still have 1 error. Any idea what need to be changed?

Comment: I've chaged as you show but still have 1 error: ERROR["test_account_activation", UserMailerTest, 2016-03-23 16:43:44 +0000]
 test_account_activation#UserMailerTest (1458751424.62s)
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:         ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'mail' for User.
            test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:4:in `block in <class:UserMailerTest>'
        test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:4:in `block in <class:UserMailerTest>'

  38/38: [=====================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:02, Time: 00:00:02

Comment: class UserMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase

  test "account_activation" do
    mail = UserMailer.account_activation(User.create(mail: "foo@bar.com"))
    assert_equal "Account activation", mail.subject
    assert_equal ["to@example.org"], mail.to
    assert_equal ["from@example.com"], mail.from
    assert_match "Hi", mail.body.encoded
  end
end

Comment: class UserMailerTest < 

ActionMailer::TestCase

  test "account_activation" do

    mail = UserMailer.account_activation(User.create(m

ail: "foo@bar.com"))

    assert_equal "Account activation", 

mail.subject

    assert_equal ["to@example.org"], mail.to

    assert_equal ["from@example.com"], 

mail.from

    assert_match "Hi", mail.body.encoded

  end

end

Comment: In my answer, I changed mail to email when creating user

Answer (score 0):

That error comes from `user_mailer_test.rb:6` line 6.

In `class UserMailer` line 3 you are passing `user` object to `def account_activation(user)` , but in your `UserMailer.account_activation` nothing passed. Keep following that book it should be example like this.

```
user = users(:michael)
user.activation_token = User.new_token
mail = UserMailer.account_activation(user) # right here user passed.
```

Answer (score 0):

test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb as below allow to get rid from one error:

require 'test_helper'

class UserMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase

test "account_activation" do

```
user = users(:tatyana)

user.activation_token = User.new_token

mail = UserMailer.account_activation(user)

assert_equal "Account activation", mail.subject

assert_equal [user.email], mail.to

assert_equal ["noreply@example.com"], mail.from

assert_match user.name,               mail.body.encoded

assert_match user.activation_token,   mail.body.encoded

assert_match CGI::escape(user.email), mail.body.encoded
```

end

end

still there is another one as below:
ERROR["test_account_activation", UserMailerTest, 2016-03-23 16:43:47 +0000]
 test_account_activation#UserMailerTest (1458751427.01s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
            app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_user_mailer_account_activation_html_erb__1635017718511086794_82209820'
            app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:5:in`account_activation'
            test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:UserMailerTest>'
        app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb:9:in`_app_views_user_mailer_account_activation_html_erb__1635017718511086794_82209820'
        app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:5:in `account_activation'
        test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:9:in`block in '

Answer (score 0):

it is solved.the error was created by not putting email options.
thanks